# VirtualBoxでカーソル位置が左上にずれる

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBoxで作成したUbuntuデスクトップの環境で、マウスをクリックした時の位置がカーソルが表示されている位置より左上にずれることが頻発しています。

起動直後は正常なのですが、しばらく使っているといつの間にかずれている、という状態が1日に数度発生します。

この現象が発生しないようにする方法はないでしょうか？

環境

- ホストOS：Windows10
- ゲストOS：ubuntu-ja-16.04-desktop-amd64
- VirtualBox：5.1.2
- GuestAddisionsはインストール済み
- 設定はフルスクリーンモードON、マウス統合ON

[image: スクリーンショット]

VM上で撮ったスクリーンショットです。
画面上ではカーソル位置は`if not c.isaln`の`c`の位置に表示されているのですが、スクリーンショットではなぜか左上の位置になっています。

尚、この現象が発生した後に元に戻すには、VMを再起動するか、以下の手順を行っています。

1. マウス統合を一旦OFFにする
2. VMの中に入ってマウスを動かす
3. 右Shiftを押してVMから抜ける
4. マウス統合をONに戻す

#### 追記

[こちら](http://qiita.com/jiz/items/a845860067ca826af7de)を参考にGuestAdditionsのバージョンを確認しました。

```
$ modinfo vboxguest
version:        5.0.18_Ubuntu

$ ls -l /usr/*/VBoxG*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 52  9月 27 12:35 /usr/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions -> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.2/lib/VBoxGuestAdditions
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54  9月 27 12:35 /usr/share/VBoxGuestAdditions -> /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.1.2/share/VBoxGuestAdditions
```

Comment: インストールした GuestAddisions のバージョンはどうなっていますか? VirtualBox 5.1.2 に付属のものをインストールしたのか、それ以前に付属していたものをそのまま使っているのか、調べて追記してください。

Comment: @KoRoN VirtualBox本体をアップグレードしたことはありますが、GuestAddisionsはそのままだったかも知れません。バージョンは明日確認してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GuestAddisionsをバージョンアップして数日使用しましたが、現象は発生しなくなりました。

## 結論

VirtualBoxをバージョンアップしたらゲストOSのGuestAddisionsもバージョンアップが必要。